# Does the C++ standard guarantee anything about algorithms operating on empty containers?

Tags: c++, std, undefined-behavior

For instance,

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> empty{};
  std::reverse(empty.begin(), empty.end());
  std::cout << "Sum: " << std::accumulate(empty.cbegin(), empty.cend(), 0) << std::endl;
  std::cout << empty.size();
}
```

builds and runs as I expect:

```
sum: 0
size: 0
```

Can I be guaranteed this behavior will happen on any standard-compliant compiler?

Comment: It's sections like [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/sort#3) that guarantee the behavior of an empty set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since standard library algorithms operate on **iterator ranges**, algorithms are **guaranteed to be safe and valid on any valid iterator range** passed to them. Now we only need to be concerned with what valid iterator range stands for.

Requirements on iterators forming an iterator range:

- They have to refer to elements (or one past the last element) of the
  same container
- It is possible to reach `end` by repeatedly incrementing `begin`. In
  other words, `end` must not precede `begin`.

After these requirements satisfied, we can think of any valid range as a **left-inclusive range**: `[begin, end)`. So then the range have the following properties:

- If `being` is equal to `end`, the range is empty
- If `begin` isn't equal to `end`, there's at least one element in the
  range, and `being` refers to the first element
- So, we can increment `begin` some number of times until `begin == end` *(when this happens, the range is still valid)*

It is these properties that provide support for the convenient usage of iterators. The `<algorithms>` internals are based on these properties as well.

We have to be aware that the **compiler cannot reinforce these requirements**, it is up to us to ensure the validity of passed range *(sometimes there are quite a few factors to consider)*.

So, yes, `begin == end` is still a valid range, when passed to an algorithm, so the output we get is also expectedly valid.

Comment: In the case of an empty container, `begin == end` so it is possible to reach `end` by incrementing `begin` zero times. So is it implied that empty containers _are_ valid operands for STL algorithms?

Comment: @segfault check the latest edit, I guess it answers this concern. Also, if we try to think how would we implement an algorithm, we would definitely incorporate something like `begin != end` in there.

Comment: @segfault a range is valid while both iters refer to the same container and  `b` doesn't go beyond `e`, means `b==e` is still valid.